# Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T7, forState: UIControlState)' in swift

Tags: swift

I have the array of Images name in NSUserDefualt.
I am trying to set those images to UIButton background image but it will give me "**Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T7, forState: UIControlState)'**" error...<>I don't understand what's it trying to say..Please help me out.
Here is my code,
`var arrayImage : NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() .arrayForKey("ImageArray")! 
btnImage.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: arrayImage[i]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `arrayImage[i]` is not `String`. The `arrayForKey` method returns an optional `Array` of `AnyObjects` (`[AnyObjects]?`). You have to convert it to a `String array` before using it. Try this code

```
if let arrayImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("ImageArray") as? [String] {
    btnImage.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: arrayImage[0]), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```